# For bounded operator $T$, Ker$(T)$ is isomorphic to Ker($T*$)

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators

Let $T$ be bounded linear functional on a Banach Space $X$. I wonder if ker$(T)$ is isomorphic is ker$(T^*)$, where $T^*$ is the Banach space dual of $T$. Note that $X$ need not be finite dimensional.

Let me discuss the source how did I come to this question.
Murphy's book "$C^*$-algebras and Operator Theory", he says that:

Theorem: Let $T$ be compact operator on a Banach Space $X$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Then $T-\lambda I$ is Fredholm and of index zero.

The next theorem easily concludes that it is Fredholm:

Theorem: Let $T$ be compact operator on a Banach Space $X$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Then

1. Ker($T-\lambda I$) is finite dimensional.
2. Im$(T-\lambda)$ is closed and finite codimensional. In fact, $\frac{X}{T-\lambda I}$ and ker$(T^*-\lambda I)$ have same dimension.

Now since $T$ is compact, then $T^*$ is compact. So Ker$(T^*-\lambda I)$ is again finite dimensional.

So, $T-\lambda I$ is Fredholm. But to show that we need show that index is zero. for that we need to show that nul($T)$=def$(T)=$ dim $\frac{X}{T-\lambda I}=$ Ker$(T^*-\lambda I)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already false for Hilbert spaces. A typical example would be given by the unilateral shift. That is, let $X=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, and
$$\tag1
T(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots). 
$$
As it is well-known, $X^*=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and
$$\tag2
T^*(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(x_2,x_3,\ldots). 
$$
Then $\ker T=\{0\}$ while $\ker T^*=\mathbb C\,(1,0,0,\dots)$. That is,
$$
\dim\ker T=0,\qquad\qquad\dim\ker T^*=1. 
$$
The same example works for any $\ell^p(\mathbb N)$, $1\leq p<\infty$. The dual is now $\ell^q(\mathbb N)$ with $q=p/(p-1)$, and the adjoint of $T$ is still as in $(2)$.

By considering $T^n$ we get examples where $\dim\ker T^n=0$ and $\dim\ker (T^*)^n=n$. And using direct sums with zero of the appropriate dimension plus switching roles if needed, one can see that for any $m,n\in\{0\}\cup\mathbb N$ there exists $T\in B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ with
$$
\dim\ker T=m,\qquad\qquad\dim\ker T^*=n.
$$